# Как выложить десктопное приложение в Microsoft Store?

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-store

Собственно за последние несколько часов я поискал и на ютубе, и в гугле, и даже по-началу предпринимал некоторое действия, пытаясь следовать инструкциям в [Microsoft Partner Center](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/account/CertificateUpload). Но ничего хорошего из этого ни вышло. Я по-прежнему не понимаю как загрузить свой приложение в MS Store.

Я даже не до конца понимаю возможно ли это? Так как в поисках информации натыкался на разные источники (в основном старые), в которых упоминался так называемый аккаунт разработчика, естественно не бесплатный.

Да и партнер центр, что-то говорит об аккаунте разработчика, хотя во время регистрации ничего не было сказано про ограничения (может я не увидел).

В общем, вопрос заключается в следующем: как запостить приложение в MS Store? Может есть материалы, в которых подробно это описывается или видео.

Comment: Магазин работает с UWP приложениями, чистый WPF вы туда не загоните. Есть некоторые технологии от MS, которые позволяют из win32 приложения сделать UWP [вроде эта](https://developer.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/bridges/desktop/) и вот если вы сделаете UWP, тогда да, его можно будет залить в магазин. Учтите, что UWP, это современные OS, на каком либо Win7 вы не запустите его больше.

Comment: Надеюсь поможет, завтра попробую. Спасибо.